# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g17sm239505vkg.44 - gsmtp "

Tags: php, email, laravel-8

This is my first time trying to use the recover password funcionality in Laravel but I'm having trouble. Gonna post the code in my env file and in the mail.php file

Env file code

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MyEmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=################ (gmail code when setting up custom less secure app)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=MyEmail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Mail.php code

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','hospitalnuestrocorazon@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','################'),

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

What I have already tried to fix the problem without success.

Refresh cache with php artisan config: cache after changes in the env file

Comment: It's telling you exactly what the problem is. `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: Also, hey look, you just posted your password.

Comment: Don't just mask the password out, people can see edits. Change it immediately.

Comment: Got it but it is a useless gmail, still better to be safe

Answer (score 1):

You are using port 587 but in your env you have

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

For laravel I would suggest to try using tls as your MAIL_ENCRYPTION parameter. This would result in

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Alex solved it first but thanks skyracer2021

Comment: Yea i wasnt sure wether the parameter was ssl or tls so I connected to ftp. Was like a minute late xD